# Why don't we have tryFlatMap operator in Combine?

Tags: swift, combine

And what shall we use instead?
I'm surprised that nobody asked this before.

Comment: As for the `why`, only Apple can answer that. As for alternatives, I don't believe there is a built-in operator that would map 1-1 to something like `tryFlatMap`, so you'll need to implement your own `Operator`.

Comment: This is a good question. I'm assuming it's downvoted because of the lack of code samples?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't strictly need `tryFlatMap`, because `flatMap`'s transform returns a publisher. You can use `do/catch` inside the transform closure and return a `Fail` publisher if you catch an error.

```
import Combine

func someFunction(of i: Int) throws -> AnyPublisher<Int, Error> {
    return Just(i + 1)
        .setFailureType(to: Error.self)
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}

let upstream: AnyPublisher<Int, Error> = Just(100)
    .setFailureType(to: Error.self)
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()

upstream
    .flatMap({ i -> AnyPublisher<Int, Error> in
        do {
            return try someFunction(of: i).eraseToAnyPublisher()
        } catch {
            return Fail(error: error).eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }
    })
```

You can write your own `tryFlatMap` operator if you like:

```
extension Publisher {
    func tryFlatMap<Pub: Publisher>(
        maxPublishers: Subscribers.Demand = .unlimited,
        _ transform: @escaping (Output) throws -> Pub
    ) -> Publishers.FlatMap<AnyPublisher<Pub.Output, Error>, Self> {
        return flatMap(maxPublishers: maxPublishers, { input -> AnyPublisher<Pub.Output, Error> in
            do {
                return try transform(input)
                    .mapError { $0 as Error }
                    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
            } catch {
                return Fail(outputType: Pub.Output.self, failure: error)
                    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
            }
        })
    }
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
upstream
    .tryFlatMap { try someFunction(of: $0) }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I came up with one more solution. I will post it below as an answer. In short: tryFlatMap = tryMap + flatMap

Answer (score 0):

One more solution.
tryFlatMap = tryMap + flatMap.

For example.
The whole story began with that I just wanted to unwrap an optional. And if it's nil I want it just to fail.

```
let upstream = Just(siteURL)
    .tryMap { url -> URL in
        guard let url = url else { throw Errors.invalidSiteURL }
        return url
    }
    .flatMap {
        URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: $0).mapError { $0 as Error }
    }
```

[Edited] Like this also works:

```
let container = Just(siteURL)
    .tryMap { url -> URLSession.DataTaskPublisher in
        guard let url = url else { throw Errors.invalidSiteURL }
        return URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
    }
    .map { $0.mapError { $0 as Error } }
    .switchToLatest()
```

Mess with error types a little annoying.